# Print a specific word when a number is div. by 5 , and another specific word when its div.by 10

Tags: python

On a range 1 to 100, I want to a specific word when the number is divisible by 5 for example "Good" , and another specific word when its divisible by 10 for example "morning"

```
1,2,3,4,good,6,7,8,9,morning .... etc
```

i made this code but its only working when its div. by 5

```
for z in range (0, 101 , 1):
    if z%5==0:
         print("good")
    
    elif z%10==0:
        print("morning")
    else:
        print(z)
```

Comment: How is it related to `javascript`?

Comment: Every number divisible by 10 is also divisible by 5. Why should Python skip the `if z%5==0` branch for `z` equal to `10`?

Comment: This is more of logical error.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the conditions for divisible by 10 or 5. If it is divisible by 10, you get "morning", then checks for 5, otherwise prints that value.

As currently written, all 10 digits will match the 5 condition, and not print further because you're using `elif`. If you used `if` twice, it would print both "good" and "morning", which doesn't match your expected output.